# How to convert string format of date as milliseconds in os x?

Tags: bash, macos

I would like to change `2020-01-17T07:41:53.000Z` to milliseconds format in os X.

How to achieve it?

Comment: [tag:macos] has a whole lot of tools available. Any specific injunctions against using the preinstalled Python or Ruby for example…? Should it use only [tag:bash] tools…?

Comment: @deceze yeah. I want to use the bash tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Converting date under Mac OS

> ```
> date '2020-01-17T07:41:53.000Z'
> date: illegal time format
> usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
>             [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
> ```

Then, from `man date`:

> ```
>  -j      Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the -f flag
>          in addition to the + option to convert one date format to
>          another.
> ```

#### Reorganizing `$str`:

```
str="2020-01-17T07:41:53.000Z"
IFS='-T:.Z' read _ccyy _mm _dd _HH _MM _ss _mil <<<"$str"
date -j +%c $_mm$_dd$_HH$_MM$_ccyy.$_ss
Fri Jan 17 07:41:53 2020
```

Seem work fine!

```
epoch=$(env TZ=UTC date -j +%s $_mm$_dd$_HH$_MM$_ccyy.$_ss)
printf -v milliseconds "%s%03.0f" $epoch $milli

echo $milliseconds
1579246913000
```

... And just: *Care about `TZ`*!

Answer (score -2):

The GNU date command `date +%s.%N` will output the seconds since
the epoch as something like:

```
1579339833.325517439
```

In order to convert the given string to the format as above on macOS bash,
would you please try the following:

```
str="2020-01-17T07:41:53.000Z"
IFS=. read datetime millisec <<< "$str"
    # split the string on "." into datetime and milliseconds
nanosec=$(( 10#${millisec%Z} * 1000000 ))
    # remove trailing "Z" from the $millisec string
    # then multiply by one million to convert to nanoseconds
printf "%s.%09d\n" $(date -d "${datetime}Z" +%s) "$nanosec"
    # convert to "epoch" with the date command and append the nanosec
```

Hope it will work.